# merging large data sets using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two large DataFrames:

- `myTable`, shape :(331994, 13). This first one contains trade data (12 columns) for several client codes (1 column)
- `Referential`, shape (75546, 1). This second one contains a referential table with client codes as indexes and client name in column 1.

I want to merge the two tables to have the names available in myTable.

I tried to merge the two tables but I keep having a `memory error`, and I'm wondering if there is a more optimal way to do this :

- Is it better to use indexes for the merge?
- Should I sort the tables before the merge?
- Should I try to filter the `referential` Table before merging to exclude client codes that don't appear in `myTable`?
- Is there a more efficient way to write this merge?
- Can I avoid the merge for such a simple operation?

I tried to look for the clientName for each line with the following code :

```
myTable["clientName"]=myTable.clientCode.apply(lambda x:
  referential.loc[x]["clientName"])
```

It works fine but it's a bit long.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the `myTable.dtypes` and `Referential.dtypes`? And could you post your `merge` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that your `Referential` DF looks like as follows:

```
   clientName
0       name1
1       name2
2       name3
```

where the index corresponds to `ClientCode`, you can use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
myTable["clientName"] = myTable.clientCode.map(Referential['clientName'])
```

Comment: Thx a lot, It runs in 38 ms, and with my previous method it took more than 10 minutes ...